# join multiple row in table by filed value

Tags: sql

i have a table `company` row like this :

| id(int) | name(string) | maincategory(int) | subcategory(string) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Google | 1 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | yahoo | 4 | 4,1 |

and other table `category` like:

| id(int) | name(string) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Search |
| 2 | Email |
| 3 | Image |
| 4 | Video |

i want to join tow table by `company.subcategory` = `category.id`

is it possible in sql ?

Comment: if you can provide example also .. it would be very simple to think accordingly ..
example means expected result .. please

Comment: using a multi-valued attribute in your tables is always a bad practice and it creates a lot of problems specially at the time of reporting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by [splitting your `subcategory` column](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str). In the end you should have an additional `company_category` table with company_id and category_id as columns.

```
 company_id(int) |category_id(int)  
 1               |1
 1               |2
 1               |3
 2               |4
 2               |1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design is invalid. You shoud have another table called companySubcategories or something like that.
This table shoud have two columns companyId an categoryId.
Then your select would look like this:

```
select <desired fields> from
company c
join companySubcategories cs on cs.companyId = cs.id
join category ct on ct.id = cs.categoryId
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below...

```
select * from 
company c, category cc
where c. subcategory like '%'||cc.id||'%';
```

it is working as expected in oracle database ..

Comment: Replace || with + and it works in MSSQL but performance will not bring us to our knees. And You forgotten about comas. When Id is 1 and You will have 11 in string column it will give a match.

Comment: you accepted answer need to changed you database architecture .. 

i thought you have this restriction ..

Comment: ypercube please describe how this query is not working as expected.. please .. 
if this query is not working then it means I didn't get requirement properly ..

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a new table `company_subcategory` to keep track of subcategories

```
  id (int) | subcategory(int)
    1      |    1
    1      |    2
    1      |    3
    2      |    1
    2      |    4
```

then you would be able to run select as

```
 select company.name AS company, category.name AS category 
   FROM company 
           JOIN company_subcategory 
                ON company.id = company_subcategory.company  
           JOIN category 
                ON company_subcategory.subcategory = category.id;
```

to get

```
+---------+----------+
| company | category |
+---------+----------+
| google  | search   |
| google  | email    |
| google  | image    |
| yahoo   | search   |
| yahoo   | video    |
+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM COMPANY CMP, CATEGORY CT
 WHERE (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN INSTR(CMP.SUB_CATEGORY, CT.ID) > 0 THEN
                  'TRUE'
                 ELSE
                  'FALSE'
               END
          FROM DUAL) = 'TRUE'
```

This query looks for the ID in the SUB_CATEGORY, using the INSTR function.
In case it does exist, the row is returned.

The output is as below

```
ID  NAME   MAIN_CATEGORY  SUB_CATEGORY   ID    NAME
1   Google  1             1,2,3        1    Search
1   Google  1             1,2,3        2    Email
1   Google  1             1,2,3        3    Image
2   yahoo   2             4,1          1    Search
2   yahoo   2             4,1          4    Video
```

Hope it helps.

However, I suggest you avoid this type of entries, as an ID should have separate entries and not combined entries. This may create problems in future, so it would be better to avoid it now.